# C# Reflection: how to get List<Employee> instead of System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Employee]?

Tags: c#, reflection

I am trying to use reflection to query the public interface of a class library, then produce classes and methods from info in the query.

The problem is that the generated source code won't compile:

- The original class library has a function parameter being "**List<Employee>**", but the generated source code has "**System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Employee]**". It is generated by **Type.ToString()**.
- The original class library has "**Dictionary<string, Employee>**", but the generated code has "**System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[string, Employee]**".

Here is the reflection code to generate source code:

```
            foreach (MethodInfo methodInfo in type.GetMethods())
            {
                if (!methodInfo.IsStatic)
                    continue;

                Console.Write($"    {(methodInfo.IsStatic ? "static" : "")} {methodInfo.ReturnType} {methodInfo.Name} (");
                ParameterInfo[] aParams = methodInfo.GetParameters();

                for (int i = 0; i < aParams.Length; i++)
                {
                    ParameterInfo param = aParams[i];

                    if (i > 0)
                        Console.Write(", ");

                    string strRefOrOut;

                    if (param.ParameterType.IsByRef)
                    {
                        if (param.IsOut)
                            strRefOrOut = "out ";
                        else
                            strRefOrOut = "ref ";
                    }
                    else
                        strRefOrOut = "";

                    Console.Write($"{ strRefOrOut }{ param.ParameterType.ToString() } {param.Name}");
                }

                Console.WriteLine(");");
            }
```

It produces the following source code that cannot be compiled:

```
static System.Void Test1 (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Employee] employees);
static System.Void Test (System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String, Employee] dict);
```

I want it to be

```
static System.Void Test1 (List<Employee> employees);
static System.Void Test (Dictionary<System.String, Employee> dict);
```

How do I get the desired outcome from the **Type**?

I don't want to do ugly "**if/else if/else if/else**" string manipulations to convert them, because if I forget to include a type of collection then it will break.

Is there an elegant way of automatically get the former, such as **Type.ProperName**?

Comment: You don't. Reflection works the way it works. You need to write your code properly to work with Reflection, not the other way around.

Comment: Maybe you should show us the relevant code and we can explain what you're doing wrong. It's hard to know what you should change when we don't know what you're doing or why.

Comment: I added the source code. Thanks!

Comment: `List<T>` is just what you wrote in C#, in VB it's `List(Of T)`, and in F# it's `List<'T>`. So you cannot expect .net core to generate language specific expression for you, you may need search some decompiler library for help.

Comment: _"because if I forget to include a type of collection"_ and these types are not types of collection, they are generic, so you can judge by `Type.IsGenericType` property.

Comment: But if I forget to include an "if/else" clause for one of the generic types, but the target class library contains this type, then my code will break.

Comment: I had hoped that Type should be able to produce a universal string representation of the type which can be understood by the compilers of all languages.

Comment: Why should it? That would require all languages to work with the same code, then they would not be different languages any more

Comment: Then you will forget these `IsStatic`, `IsByRef`... in the code either, the code will still break.

Comment: *"But if I forget to..."*. If I forget to write the proper code in any situation then my application won't work. It's not the job of the language authors to change the language so I can forget to write the proper code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want what Reflection provides directly then you need to write your own method to do what you actually want. Here's an example that will generate C#-style names for most types, so you can just call it every time and get the correct result:

```cs
private static string GetTypeName(Type type)
{
    var typeName = type.Name;

    if (!type.IsGenericType)
    {
        return typeName;
    }

    typeName = typeName.Substring(0, typeName.IndexOf('`'));

    var parameterTypeNames = type.GetGenericArguments().Select(GetTypeName);

    typeName = $"{typeName}<{string.Join(", ", parameterTypeNames)}>";

    return typeName;
}
```

This ignores namespaces and use .NET names, e.g. "String" rather than "string". You can change those things if you want. If you do omit namespaces, you'd have to make sure that appropriate imports were written too.